# How to assign dynamic placeholder to Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I know this question is asked before for assigning text to textbox, but they didn't have answers or the given answers didn't work for me. I have a static function for translations and I'm trying to use that to assign a placeholder to a Textbox. How can I do it in aspx page?

My code is:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server" 
    placeholder='<%# islem.DilGetir(7) %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
```

This one returns this sourcecode:

```
<input name="ctl00$search" type="text" id="ctl00_search">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ajax controll toolkit text box watermark I find it to be mnost usefull in aspx apps

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx

```
 <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID ="search" WatermarkText="textthe my name" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
        </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

on the back end

```
TextBoxWatermarkExtender1.WatermarkTex=islem.DilGetir(7);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set this attribute from the page `code behind`:

```
search.Attributes["placeholder"] = islem.DilGetir(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. The exact solution: Take all placeholder's text to hiddenfield component(separated with , ) and with JS, take the inside array hiddenfield text and assign to input text's placeholder attr with jQuery or JS.

Answer (score 0):

this code for multiselectbox choosen js and normal selectbox.

```
public void SelectFill(DataTable dtResult, HtmlSelect htmlSelect, string placeHolder, string textColumn, string valueColumn, string value)
    {
        htmlSelect.DataSource = dtResult;
        htmlSelect.DataTextField = textColumn;
        htmlSelect.DataValueField = valueColumn;
        htmlSelect.DataBind();

        bool isMultiple = false;
        foreach (var item in htmlSelect.Attributes.Keys)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == "multiple")
            {
                isMultiple = true;
            }
        }

        if (isMultiple)
        {
            htmlSelect.Attributes["data-placeholder"] = placeHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            ListItem placeHolderItem = new ListItem(placeHolder, "-1");//create placeholder option for non multible selectbox
            placeHolderItem.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            htmlSelect.Items.Insert(0, placeHolderItem);
            htmlSelect.Items[0].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```